# I can't refresh page to top using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I used this code but it didn't work, I need some help about how to refresh page to top when it loads.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   window.scrollTo(0,0)
})

window.onload = (event) => {
   window.scrollTo(0,0)
};
```

Comment: Your code works. Something else breaks it

Answer (score 2):

Your code works if the page is loading not at top

For example on a back button or if the page is loaded with an ID in the hash

You CAN just remove the onload and have the script inline at the bottom of the page

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   window.scrollTo(0,0)
})
```

```css
div { height: 500px; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div>Div</div>
<div id="x">Last Div</div>
<script>
 // mocking the page loading not at top, this is not part of the answer
 document.getElementById("x").scrollIntoView(); //while loading
 
 // put the window.scrollTo(0,0) here if you have issues
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.scrollTo(0,0)` can you try using `document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

Your code should become

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
})

window.onload = (event) => {
   document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
};
```

Comment: If OP's code does not work where he put it, then your code won't either

Comment: @mplungjan I see, thanks for the headsup!